# CheerioJS to parse data on script tag

Tags: html, json, web-scraping, cheerio, html-entities

I've been trying to parse the data that is in the script tag using cheerio however It's been difficult for the following reasons.

- Can't parse string that is generated into JSON because of html-entities

More Info:

- Also what is strange to me is that you have to re-load the content into cheerio a second time to get the text.

Your welcome to fork this replit or copy and paste the code to try it yourself
https://replit.com/@Graciasc/Cheerio-Script-Parse

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const {decode} = require('html-entities')
const html = `
<body>

 <script type="text/javascript"src="/data/common.0e95a19724a68c79df7b.js"></script>

<script>require("dynamic-module-registry").set("from-server-context", JSON.parse("\x7B\x22data\x22\x3A\x7B\x22available\x22\x3Atrue,\x22name\x22\x3A"Gracias"\x7D\x7D"));</script> 

</body>
`;
  const $ = cheerio.load(html, {
    decodeEntities: false,
  });
  const text = $('body').find('script:not([type="text/javascript"])');
  const cheerioText = text.eq(0).html();

  //implement a better way to grab the string
  const scriptInfo = cheerio.load(text.eq(0).html()).text();
    const regex = new RegExp(/^.*?JSON.parse\(((?:(?!\)\);).)*)/);
    const testing = regex.exec(scriptInfo)[1];

  // real output: 
//\x7B\x22data\x22\x3A\x7B\x22available\x22\x3Atrue,\x22name\x22\x3A"Gracias"\x7D\x7D when logged
    console.log(testing)

    // Not Working
    const json = JSON.parse(testing)

   
    const decoding = decode(testing)
    // same output as testing
    console.log(decoding)
   
// Not working
    console.log('decode', JSON.parse(decoding))
```

```js
//JSON
{ Data: { available: true, name: 'Gracias' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution is to use JSDOM

repl.it link( https://replit.com/@Graciasc/Cheerio-Script-Parse#index.js)

```js
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom')

const dom = new JSDOM(`<body>

 <script type="text/javascript"src="/data/common.0e95a19724a68c79df7b.js"></script>

<script>require("dynamic-module-registry").set("from-server-context", JSON.parse("\x7B\x22data\x22\x3A\x7B\x22available\x22\x3Atrue,\x22name\x22\x3A"Gracias"\x7D\x7D"));</script> 

</body>`)


const serializedDom = dom.serialize()

const regex = new RegExp(/^.*?JSON.parse\("((?:(?!"\)\);).)*)/gm);
const jsonString = regex.exec(serializedDom)[1];


console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString))
// output: { data: { available: true, name: 'Gracias' } }
```